# Flutter App Bundle not Working on Google Play Release

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle, google-play, android-app-bundle

This is the first time I'm uploading an app on Google Play!

#### Functionality

The app is developed with flutter and for backend I use firebase, the app uses the phones camera, storage and I also have push notifications. I have setup the Firebase App Check for both app attest and Play integrity but for the time being I haven't enforced it from the firebase console!

#### Release

During testing and a private release version to the dev team devices with the **apk** of the app it worked perfectly fine, it is when I deploy the **App Bundle (.aab)** on the play store the app downloads, then the splash screen is presented for a second and then saying `Something went wrong with <app-name>` `<app-name> closed because this app has a bug.`
Note: The iOS version of the app is working perfectly fine from the app store, so I assume something is wrong with the android version.

##### Extra info regarding Bundle

I followed the flutter docs to release the app, so the code Obfuscation and minification by R8 is used. And the app is signed based on the doc instructions!

To deploy the app to the app store I used xcode and uploaded an archive on the app store connect, I read a comment saying not to use the flutter build command and use android studio to deploy my app but I don't think that's the case.

This is the stack trace provided by the Google play console

`dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException

Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner (LoadedApk.java:1573)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner (LoadedApk.java:1502)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:7537)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2397)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8741)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication (AppComponentFactory.java:76)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication (CoreComponentFactory.java)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:1232)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner (LoadedApk.java:1565)
```

After searching I came across a lot of people mentioning dalvik and to add the multidex dependency to the gradle.build file but I read on the android docs that this is useful when you target minSDK < 20 but I'm targeting minSDK 22 so I'm not quite sure if that will fix my issue.

I also found people mentioning that the R8 obfuscation is causing them problems either directly with the app bundle or with firebase but at first I would like to keep the obfuscation for security purposes.

### My build.gradle

```java
...
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### My android manifest

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="XXX"
        android:name="XXX"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any comments or notes that you can provide would be really appreciated, also a quick note I do not usually post on SO because I typically find a solution by searching but this time around I feel completely lost after hours of searching so please be understanding.
Thank you in advance!